# The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using .net Framework 4.5.2. I am running MVC application. As i got new laptop I am getting the issue when running the MVC Application.

ERROR:

> The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Microsoft Studio Professional 2017
Version : 15.9.12

In other teammates VS version is 15.8.1. Where it is running without any issue.

I have also installed MVC 4 and Missing plugins. Still, I am getting this issue.

please suggest to me what I need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396711/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced

Comment: You say you are using Framework yet the error indicates Standard. Does your solution contain a project in Standard?

Comment: You cannot consume .NET Standard 2.0 based things in a project targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2. Upgrade to at least 4.6.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925484/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-version-2-0-0-0)

Answer (score 4):

Deleting Bin and Obj folders worked for me.